# how to transfer netcdf to binary IN PYTHON

Tags: python, binary, netcdf

I want to know how to translate a netcdf file to a binary file IN PYTHON. I have some timeseries data in a netcdf file. I want to change it to a binary file so that I can run TIMESAT to extract phenological metrics.

Has someone already solved this problem? Or can I use Arcmap to build models to do this process?

Comment: You can read a NetCDF file with e.g. the `NetCDF4` package, and write data in binary format with `open(...., "wb")`.

Comment: don't forget too that you can calculate a lot of useful metrics directly on the netcdf file itself using CDO from the command line

Answer (score 2):

NCO converts netCDF to binary as illustrated [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#binary), e.g.,

```
ncks -C -O -v one_dmn_rec_var -b bnr.dat -p ~/nco/data in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `gdal_translate` to convert from netcdf to binary.  See:
http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/timesat.asp?cat=5
and
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

My favorite way to install gdal is with conda.  Download anaconda or miniconda and for free from https://www.anaconda.com/ and then do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, basiclly I know Timesat well, but for gdal_translate, I don'tn know how to use fot data conversion especially I need from NETCDF to BINARY. Do you have examples? or give me more information about how to use  gdal_translate. Thanks!